# how could i change the JSON structure..?

Tags: javascript, json

the Response which i get from Back-end is below structure JSON.

```
[
{
"carrier": "Emirates",
"stops": "stops-0",
"date": "Jul 18",
"min": 1407,
"avg": 1407,
"max": 1407
},
  {
"carrier": "Ethiopian Airlines",
"stops": "stops-1",
"date": "Jul 19",
"min": 5151,
"avg": 5151,
"max": 5151
}
]
```

Need to change the structure as below

```
[
{
"carrier": "Emirates",
"stops": "stops-0",
"date": "Jul 18",
"min": 1407,
},
{
"carrier": "Emirates",
"stops": "stops-0",
"date": "Jul 18",
"avg": 1407,
},
{
"carrier": "Emirates",
"stops": "stops-0",
"date": "Jul 18",
"max": 1407
},
  {
"carrier": "Ethiopian Airlines",
"stops": "stops-1",
"date": "Jul 19",
"min": 5151,
},
 {
"carrier": "Ethiopian Airlines",
"stops": "stops-1",
"date": "Jul 19",
"avg": 5151,
},
 {
"carrier": "Ethiopian Airlines",
"stops": "stops-1",
"date": "Jul 19",
"max": 5151
}
]
```

the data which i need to convert as range, the ranges are min,avg,max .. is that possible to convert the data in javascript..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course many ways to do this, but I'll show you one:

You can replace each entry by three individual ones, flattening the array in the process.

```js
function convert (arr) {
  return arr.flatMap(({ min, avg, max, ...commonFields }) => [
    { ...commonFields, min },
    { ...commonFields, avg },
    { ...commonFields, max }
  ])
}
```

The [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) function is like a combination of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (with which you can map each element of an array to a newly calculated one, getting a new array with all elements mapped at the end) and [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (to "flatten" nested arrays, i.e. turning `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]` into `[a, b, c, d, e, f]`).

We are hereby replacing each element with three elements, having the properties that you want. The `...commonFields` syntax allows us to pass around all the remaining fields (`carrier`, `stops`, `date` in your case) as one object instead of listing them individually.

(Thanks to commenter adiga - I had a solution with `map` and `flat` and forgot that `flatMap` exists.)

Comment: You could collect the common properties in a `rest` variable `({ min, avg, max, ...rest })` and use: `{ ...rest, min }` etc to create the objects. Also, `arr.flatMap` instead of `arr.map(...).flat()`